# Android increase gridview click speed

Tags: android, gridview, performance

I'm using a GridView in Android. I need to register as many clicks as possible, but gridview reacts to clicks very slow, even if there is no acutal code to execute... is there a possibility to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application, you might want to code up a custom component.

I had a similar problem and replaced the old gridview with a component based on TableLayout. It was more work, but was worth it in the end (faster and more flexible).

Here's a handy article to get you started:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html